# How to replace text with current filename in VIM?

Tags: file, vim, replace

I suppose my question in not that clear but let me try to explain it here.

Let's suppose I have opened a file named `myfilename.java` with the below content

```
public class test{
}
```

Now, what I want is to replace `test` with `myfilename`. Now to get the filename in vim I used `:echo expand('%:r')` which gave me `myfilename`.

Now, my question is how to do I use the above output and replace `test` with it and map it to a key for future use. What I need is may be something like:

```
:%s/test/above_output_from_command/g
```

Comment: just a note that if you want the filename in there without extension you should probably use expand('%:t:r') in case you are editing a file which is in a different directory than the working directory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add `\=` to tell Vim you're trying to call a function:

```
:%s/test/\=expand('%:r')/g
```

See `:help sub-replace-expression`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and link to the documentation.

Comment: :%s/test/\=expand('%:t:r')/g
As indicated in my comment from above it's best to use :t as well so you only ever get the filename not part of the path

Comment: I could only get this to work if the expansion was the entire replacement argument. Adding text like `:%s/test/put this before \=expand('%:r')/g` caused the expand to fail.

Comment: @JosiahYoder The `\=` must be at the start of the replacement. You’d want to use string concatenation like `s/test/\="put this before" . expand('%:r')/`. Again, see the Vim help for more.

Comment: Thank you. This is a new area of Vim for me.  What is the code after the \= called?

Comment: @JosiahYoder An expression. Again, I suggest reading the help within Vim which is referenced in the answer. Vim’s built-in `:help` is fantastic when you find the correct section.

Comment: Yes -- it's that finding the correct section which is the hard part! And now I see you already answered that in your question above. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

For my application, I ended up using a keybound macro (not sure what the VIM) name for this is) that did the edit I want and simply inserted the filename where I wanted it:

`:nmap <F5> 0d$:put =expand('%:p:t')^M0ipackage ^[$a;^[`

In my case, I wanted to insert the name of the containint directory instead of the file, so I used:

`:nmap <F5> 0d$:put =expand('%:p:h:t')^M0ipackage ^[$a;^[`

The `0d$` deletes the contents of the current line, `:put =expand('%:p:t')^M` inserts the filename, and the remaining commands edit the line around the command to produce something like

`package containing_directory;`

on the current line.